# How do you generate binary and hex files from a toolchain?

Tags: bazel

I'm building a cc_binary hello_world application with a gnu arm gcc cross compiler toolchain. In my `toolchain_config.bzl` file, I have the tool paths defined to include things like the gcc tool, ld tool, objcopy tool, etc. How do I edit my toolchain such that it automatically calls the objcopy tool and generates .hex and .bin files when I run my bazel build? At the moment, it only looks like the compiler and linker tools and associated actions get called.

It looks like maybe an action_config is the right approach, and then from there I can specify a feature with flag groups that are associated with that action (i.e. an action that calls `objcopy -o binary hello_world hello_world.bin`). However, I can't seem to get the implementation correct. Currently, I have a feature whose actions are associated with all of the objc `ACTION_NAMES` from `@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/cc:action_names.bzl`. My code builds, but it does not trigger any objcopy actions.

I know that a common way to do this is to use a genrule and have it call my cc_binary in the tools parameter. I was able to get this to work, however, it seems like a cleaner way to do this would be to have it automatically called from the toolchain since it's defined in the tool path anyway. Any advice or references would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I've written my own 'objcopy' rule that uses 'find_cc_toolchain(ctx).cc_toolchain.objcopy_executable' to get the path to the objcopy tool from the cc_toolchain.
Might not be exactly what you are looking for, but at least better than a genrule...

```
load("@rules_cc//cc:find_cc_toolchain.bzl", "find_cc_toolchain")

def _objcopy_impl(ctx):
    cc_toolchain = find_cc_toolchain(ctx)
    outfile = ctx.outputs.out
    infile = ctx.file.src

    ctx.actions.run_shell(
        outputs = [outfile],
        inputs = depset(
            direct = [ctx.file.src],
            transitive = [
                cc_toolchain.all_files,
            ],
        ),
        command = "{objcopy} {args} {src} {dst}".format(
            objcopy = cc_toolchain.objcopy_executable,
            args = ctx.attr.args,
            src = ctx.file.src.path,
            dst = ctx.outputs.out.path,
        ),
    )

    return [
        DefaultInfo(
            files = depset([outfile]),
        ),
    ]

objcopy = rule(
    implementation = _objcopy_impl,
    attrs = {
        # Source file
        "src": attr.label(allow_single_file = True, mandatory = True),
        # Target file
        "out": attr.output(mandatory = True),
        # Arguments
        "args": attr.string(mandatory = True),
    },
    executable = False,
    toolchains = ["@bazel_tools//tools/cpp:toolchain_type"],
    fragments = ["cpp"],
)
```